# Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0 Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm developing code in php, in app engine flexible environment. I'm trying to set up the SDK Admin, web version, for Firebase.

Currently, I'm just struggling with the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        
        type: 'GET',
        url: "prueba.js",
        dataType: 'json'
        
    }).done(function(res){
        
        console.log("Todo bien!");
        
    }).fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,err){
        
        console.log(err);
        
    });
```

Aforementioned code is calling through AJAX the following code (that is, 'prueba.js'):

```
var admin = require(firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('path/to/json-key.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://<database>.firebaseio.com'
});
```

These code throws the exception:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at n.parseJSON (jquery.min.js:4)
    at ub (jquery.min.js:4)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

...and last but not least, the folder and files organisation:

> 'node_modules', containing firebase-admin, is located in the root folder ('web'), along with index.js, package.json and package-lock.json
>
> Prueba.html and prueba.js are located in the path 'web/asg/trm/admin'

package.json in the 'web' folder holds the following code:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

'index.js', on the opposite hand, does not contain any code.

I have tested the following:

- In 'require' (in 'prueba.js'), I've been juggling with different locations for the 'node_modules' folder (pointing directly to the 'package.json' comprised in 'firebase-admin' as well).

Due to my short experience in Node.js, I've been spending the last two days trying to make ends meet, with no success. So any kind help would be more than welcome!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: share you json file, may be your json file structure will be wrong.

Comment: You're trying to read a JavaScript code file as JSON, and it's not. You need to set up a webserver in Node in order to run that code; it will not run in the browser. The `v` it's complaining about is the first letter of `var`.

Comment: ^^ What Heretic Monkey said. Also, separately, you have a typo, missing opening `'`: `var admin = require(firebase-admin');` This would prevent the code from running at all.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>     url: "prueba.js",
>     dataType: 'json'
> ```

You're asking for a JavaScript file, but telling jQuery to parse it as JSON.

This is the first line of that JavaScript file:

> ```
> var admin = require(firebase-admin');
> ```

… that the first character in it is the `v` that is being reported as an unexpected token. JSON cannot start with a `v`, but as mentioned what you have is not JSON.

It isn't client-side JavaScript either, it looks like it is intended to be part of a server-side program run on Node.js, which you said you were trying to use.

For some reason, you aren't running it using Node.js at all, but are delivering the source code to the web browser.

You could write your server-side program as a web service (the [express library](https://expressjs.com/) is popular for this) and then run it with Node.js. You should then set the `url` to be the URL of the end point you create with that.